# Unable to retrive user information using Twitter4j library

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have written following java code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException, IOException {
//FROM HERE 
        Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("i use my keys here", "i use my keys");
    RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
    AccessToken accessToken = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (null == accessToken) {
      System.out.println("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
      System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
      System.out.print("Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:");
      String pin = br.readLine();
      try{
         if(pin.length() > 0){
           accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
         }else{
           accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
         }
      } catch (TwitterException te) {
        if(401 == te.getStatusCode()){
          System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
        }else{
          te.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }


    IDs frndlst = twitter.getFollowersIDs(1);
    long idlist[] = frndlst.getIDs();
    for(int i=0;i<idlist.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(idlist[i]);
    }
    //TO HERE CO IS WORKING
    //HERE I AM TRYING TO GET IDS OF MY FOLLOWERS BUT ITS NOT WORKING
        System.out.println(idlist.toString());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(frndlst);

        //HERE AGAIN I AM TRYING BUT STILL NOT WORKING      
    PagableResponseList<User> l1 = twitter.getFollowersList("varun_karhadkar", 10);

    System.out.println("checking if empty"+ l1.isEmpty());
    System.out.println(l1);
    System.exit(0);
  }


}
```

Need some help, All I want to do is get the screen name of all the users following me and list of all the users I am following to.

Output after executing above code:-

```
Open the following URL and grant access to your account:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=vXrXa5eaDMkTNd66bInW7e6u7WMX1yGiLmSD9h4
Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:9045949

[J@694bc02d

IDsJSONImpl{ids=[], previousCursor=-1, nextCursor=0}

checking if empty true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong because you are calling getFollowersIDs() function by value 1. 
However, you should call that function with your user id value which is unique for each user on Twitter. You can find your user id by searching on this web page : http://gettwitterid.com/.

After that, you just need to call the function with that user id.

In addition, I don't know why `twitter.getFollowersList("varun_karhadkar", 10);` code did not work. Probably, the reason is you are giving 10 instead of -1 for the cursor value first.

Try those that I said above. It should work because I have used same code.

Comment: Same thing should work for the users you are following like twitter.getFriendsIDs(userId);